# LED at full brightness after dim button is not touched for certain amount of time

Tags: c++, arduino

I made a simple 1 button LED dimmer and I would like to have the LED go back to full brightness after the button has not been touched for a set amount of time. But the code I came up with does not seem to be working as I cannot dim the LED

```
int buttonPin = 12;
int LEDPin = 3;
int buttonVal;
int LEDbright = 0;
int dt = 500;
int fdt = 60000;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long whenButtonWasTouchedMs = 0;
  buttonVal = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  Serial.print("Button = ");
  Serial.print(buttonVal);
  Serial.print(", ");

  delay(dt);

  if (buttonVal == 1) {
    LEDbright = LEDbright + 20;
    whenButtonWasTouchedMs = millis();
    
  }
  Serial.println(LEDbright);
  //
  if (LEDbright > 255) {
    LEDbright = 255;
    delay(dt);
  }

  unsigned long afterButtonWasTouchedMs = millis() - whenButtonWasTouchedMs;

  if (afterButtonWasTouchedMs >= 60000) {
    LEDbright = 0;

    analogWrite(LEDPin, LEDbright);
  }
}
```

Comment: You only write the value when you reset it to zero?

Comment: when what resets to zero? sorry I'm a bit of and Arduino coding noob

Comment: When you do `LEDbright = 0` you call `analogWrite`, you don't call `analogWrite` anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't seem to line up with how the code was written. It looks like you want to do the opposite (have the light get brighter when the button is held down, and then switch off 60 seconds after the button was released).
Here's the code I came up with to help with your stated problem:

```
int buttonPin = 12;
int LEDPin = 3;
int buttonVal;
int whenButtonWasTouched;
unsigned int LEDbright = 255;
int dt = 500;
int fdt = 60000;
unsigned long whenButtonWasTouchedMs = 0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //static unsigned long whenButtonWasTouchedMs = 0;
  buttonVal = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  Serial.print("Button = ");
  Serial.print(buttonVal);
  Serial.print(", ");

  delay(dt);

  if (buttonVal == 1) {
    LEDbright = LEDbright - 20;
    whenButtonWasTouchedMs = millis();
    
  }

  //
  if (LEDbright < 20 || LEDbright > 255) { // The LEDbright > 255 part is because sometimes there can be an integer overflow if we don't keep this.
    LEDbright = 0;
  }  
  Serial.println(LEDbright);

  unsigned long afterButtonWasTouchedMs = millis() - whenButtonWasTouched;

  if (afterButtonWasTouchedMs >= 60000) {
    LEDbright = 255;
  }    
  analogWrite(LEDPin, LEDbright);
}
```

As you can see I changed it so that analogWrite is not in the if statement, it checks for integer overflows, and prints out the adjusted value for the led brightness. To make it grow brighter as the button is held and then switch off after 60 seconds just change the minus sign to a plus sign in the LEDbright adjustment line, and change some of the other values around.

Comment: at 255 the LED is off at 0 on

Comment: That wasn't the case for my board.

Comment: I posted the working code, thanks for the help. had to remove this as it made the LED cycle if the button was kept pressed 
`if (LEDbright < 20 || LEDbright > 255) { // The LEDbright > 255 part is because sometimes there can be an integer overflow if we don't keep this.
    LEDbright = 0;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
int buttonPin = 12;
int LEDPin = 3;
int buttonVal;

unsigned int LEDbright = 0;
int dt = 500;
int fdt = 60000;
unsigned long whenButtonWasTouchedMs = 0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //static unsigned long whenButtonWasTouchedMs = 0;
  buttonVal = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  Serial.print("Button = ");
  Serial.print(buttonVal);
  Serial.print(", ");

  delay(dt);

  if (buttonVal == 1) {
    LEDbright = LEDbright + 20;
    whenButtonWasTouchedMs = millis();
    
  }

  if (LEDbright > 255) {
    LEDbright = 255;
    delay(dt);
  } 
  Serial.println(LEDbright);

  unsigned long afterButtonWasTouchedMs = millis() - whenButtonWasTouchedMs;

  if (afterButtonWasTouchedMs >= 60000) {
    LEDbright = 0;
  }    
  analogWrite(LEDPin, LEDbright);
}
```